# Need to delay credits after a debit in Balanced Payments

Tags: balanced-payments

Background: The website is designed for property managers and tenants to do the following - 
1. Property Manager registers for the site
2. Property Manager creates their Tenant users
3. Property Manager and Tenant verify their own bank accounts using Balanced Payments from our site
4. Once verified, the Tenant logs in, enters an amount to pay to the Property Manager and submits payment
5. Amount entered by Tenant is debited from their account using ACH and placed in Marketplace
6. Marketplace automatically credits rent amount to Property Manager (minus a $7.50 transaction fee).

The problem I have is when the Tenant pays, the debit is created in the log, but the credit has a 409 error "insufficient marketplace funds"; does anyone know how to remedy this error?  Should I/Can I put a delay on the issuing of the credit until the debit is actually received in the Marketplace?  I have several screenshots if it would help..

Thank you in advance for the assistance,

Jake
Founder, RentEater.com

Answer (score 2):

You're using ACH, or bank account, debits here. Due to the asynchronous nature of the ACH network, these debits don't succeed immediately, like credit card debits do. They are batch-settled once per day, and take around 3 business days to succeed. This page has some more information on this process:

https://www.balancedpayments.com/ach-debits

One way to work around this is to keep a reserve of funds in your marketplace's escrow account, so that you can pay out credits immediately after creating a debit. The credit will come from this reserve, which will be replenished when the debit succeeds.